# Insert image filepath into cell as hyperlink and image itself into comment

Tags: image, excel, filepath, vba

I'm trying to create an Excel macro that takes a picture or pictures as input. It then adds the image as a comment to the selected cell. I have this much complete.

What I want to do next is take the path of the picture and insert it as a hyperlink in the cell.
e.g.
Image - \server\share\test\image.jpg
Insert image as comment
Insert image path as text

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub ImageLinkComment()

Dim Pict() As Variant
Dim ImgFileFormat As String
Dim PictCell As Range
Dim lLoop As Long
Dim sShape As Picture

ActiveSheet.Protect False, False, False, False, False
ImgFileFormat = "All Picture Files(*.emf;*.wmf;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jfif;*.jpe;*.png;*.bpm;*.gif;*.gfa;*.emz;*.wmz;*.pcz;*.tif;*.tiff;*.cgm;*.eps;*.pct;*.pict;*.wpg;*.pcd;*.pcx;*.cdr;*.fpx;*.mix), *.bmp"

 'Note you can load in any nearly file format
Pict = Application.GetOpenFilename(ImgFileFormat, MultiSelect:=True)
If Not IsArray(Pict) Then
    Debug.Print "No files selected."
    Exit Sub
End If

Set PictCell = Selection.Cells(1)
For lLoop = LBound(Pict) To UBound(Pict)

    PictCell.AddComment
    PictCell.Comment.Visible = False
    PictCell.Comment.Shape.Height = 215
    PictCell.Comment.Shape.Width = 195
    PictCell.Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture Pict(lLoop)

    Set PictCell = PictCell.Offset(1)
Next lLoop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some playing around I got this code to work for one image at a time. It's not the prettiest but it's functional.
I assigned it to a button within my excel sheet, along with another button to clear the contents of a cell.

```
Sub InsertImagesAsComments()

Dim Pict
Dim ImgFileFormat As String
Dim PictCell As Range
Dim lLoop As Long
Dim sShape As Picture

ActiveSheet.Protect False, False, False, False, False
ImgFileFormat = "All Picture Files(*.emf;*.wmf;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jfif;*.jpe;*.png;*.bpm;*.gif;*.gfa;*.emz;*.wmz;*.pcz;*.tif;*.tiff;*.cgm;*.eps;*.pct;*.pict;*.wpg;*.pcd;*.pcx;*.cdr;*.fpx;*.mix), *.bmp"

 'Note you can load in any nearly file format

Pict = Application.GetOpenFilename(ImgFileFormat, MultiSelect:=False)
If Pict = False Then Exit Sub

Set PictCell = Selection.Cells(1)

PictCell.AddComment
PictCell.Comment.Visible = False
PictCell.Comment.Shape.Height = 215
PictCell.Comment.Shape.Width = 195
PictCell.Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture Pict
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
    Pict, _
    TextToDisplay:= _
    Pict

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Purpose of this code is to fetch the images from the file path and place them as comment in the adjacent row.

Assummning there are 5 file path in A1 to A5, the code asks to select the range, and then it puts the image as comment in B1 to B5.

Hope it helps someone

```
Sub Filepath_to_Picture_As_Comments()

Dim cmt As Comment
Dim rng As Range
Dim Workrng As Range
Dim Height As Long
Dim Width As Long

On Error Resume Next

xTitleId = "Select range of File paths"
Set Workrng = Application.Selection
Set Workrng = Application.InputBox("File paths", xTitleId, Workrng.Address, Type:=8)

Height = Application.InputBox("Add text", "Height of comment", "400", Type:=2)
Width = Application.InputBox("Add text", "Width of comment", "500", Type:=2)

For Each rng In Workrng
  With rng.Offset(0, 1)
    Set cmt = rng.Comment
    If cmt Is Nothing Then
      Set cmt = .AddComment
    End If
    With cmt
      .Text Text:=""
      .Shape.Fill.UserPicture rng.Value
      .Visible = False
    End With
  End With
Next rng

For Each cmt In Application.ActiveSheet.Comments
    cmt.Shape.Width = Width
    cmt.Shape.Height = Height
Next cmt

End Sub
```